# How to turn off ffmpeg dithering?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a video to an animated gif, and I actually want it to have banding, so I'm trying to turn off dithering.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1:24 -t 2 -i *.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=15,scale=sws_dither=none:w=480:h=-1,split [a][b];[a] palettegen=max_colors=4:stats_mode=single [p];[b][p] paletteuse=new=1" avengers3.gif
```

Here's what the output from the above looks like:

[image]

It seems to me that definitely still has dithering, so how to turn it off?

It said in the docs that sws_dither is the flag to set to "none" to disable dithering - perhaps I'm passing that wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html tells you the sws_dither is the dither algorithm whereas https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse tells you to turn the dither off.

The answer to your question is to set

```
paletteuse=dither=none
```

BTW, http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html gives you the result of the paletteuse settings.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. For future note, I needed to change paletteuse=new=1 to paletteuse=new=1:dither=none

Comment: Thanks for this; annoyingly the paletteuse docs don't list `none` as an option (confirmed they didn't on Nov 17 2020, either, just as a sanity check). ‍♂️ It works though (in 4.3.2 at least).

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9950 re: documentation

Comment: It's been added to the docs as of today, according to the ticket.